# OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'polylines' for Line Detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have some hundreds lines of code for Lane Detection problem, and I get an error in the very last cell. The line

```
cv2.polylines(pred_bin_rgb, [inst.astype(np.int32)], False, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

causes error

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-65ad52360cb6> in <module>
    131 
    132                     cv2.polylines(rgb, [inst.astype(np.int32)], False, (0, 0, 255), 2)
--> 133                     cv2.polylines(pred_bin_rgb, [inst.astype(np.int32)], False, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    134                     cv2.polylines(pred_inst_rgb, [inst.astype(np.int32)], False, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    135 

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'polylines'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'`
```

I checked `pred_bin_rgb.dtype`, and got `dtype('int64')` (Though should be an image, right?)
However, when I hover over it in the code line, it says `ndarray` with shape `(512, 256, 3)`.

I'm confused what to fix. This is the variable defined earlier:

```
pred_bin_rgb = pred_bin_batch[idx].repeat(3,1,1).cpu().numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255
```

Comment: "and got dtype('int64')" -- I don't think `cv::Mat` supports 64bit integers...

Comment: @DanMašek I believe it's true, but changing through astype didn't work.